# Missing required parameter for [Route: companies.show] [URI: company/{company}] [Missing parameter: company]

Tags: laravel

Estoy intentando listar y generar enlaces dinámicamente unos registros de mi base de datos, pero cuando intento acceder a la página *index.blade.php* me sale el error "Missing required parameter for [Route: companies.show] [URI: company/{company}] [Missing parameter: company]"

Este es el código que estoy usando:

**Web.php**

```
Route::get('/companies',[CompanyController::class, "index"])->name('companies.index');
Route::get('/company/{company}', [CompanyController::class, "show"])->name('companies.show');
```

**CompanyController.php**

```
public function index(){
    $companies = Company::orderBy('id','desc')->paginate();
    return view('companies.index', compact('companies'));
}
public function show( Company $company){
    return view('companies.show', compact('company'));
}
```

**index.blade.php**

```html
@extends('layouts.plantilla')

@section('title','Companies')

@section('content')
    <h1>Welcom to Companies</h1>
    <a href="{{route('companies.create')}}">Create a company</a>
    <ul>
        @foreach($companies  as $company)
            <li>
               Esta es la linea en la que me salta el error-> <a href="{{route('companies.show', $company)}}">{{$company->name}}</a>
                <br/>
            </li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
    {{$companies->links()}}
@endsection
```

La versión de Laravel que estoy usando es la 8.51.0

Comment: Prueba así `route('companies.show', ['company' => $company->id]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

y si intentas $company->id EN TU HREF?